# Find families of lines covering surface

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider surface $x_1^2-x_2^2-2x_3=0$ I need to find families of set which cover this surface , how should I approach this problem ?

Comment: Do you mean a family of tangent lines of this surface?

Comment: what you mean by tangent ? In task it's mentioned just lines covering this surface

Comment: I see. Then Holonomia's answer is a smart one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $$\begin{cases} x_1 = t - s \\ x_2 = s \\ x_3 = \frac{t^2}{2} - st\end{cases}$$  the you can check that $x_1^2 - x_2^2 - 2x_3 = 0$. 
Moreover for each $t$ fixed the curve $s \to (t-s, s, \frac{t^2}{2} -st)$ is a line. Finally, notice that such lines cover the surface since you can recover $s$ from $x_2$ and $t$ from $x_1,x_2$.

I got the above family of lines by using the following trick:
$$x_1 + x_2 = \frac{2x_3}{x_1 - x_2} = t $$
Then I solved the linear system $$\begin{cases} x_1 + x_2 = t \\
2x_3 = t(x_1 - x_2) \end{cases}$$
where $t$ is a parameter and $s = x_2$.

Comment: so the answer is two families with respect to $s \to $ and $t \to$ ?

Comment: and what if $x_1=x_2$ then denominator is 0

Comment: Yes, you have two families, but just one of them are straight lines of $\mathbb{R}^3$.    What is important are the formulae given $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in terms of $t,s$.  That $x_1 = x_2$  and a denominator is 0 is not important since it is in an intermediate passage to get the valid  formulae for all values of $s,t$. Namely, we can just delete the explanation of how I got the formulae and everything is OK.